# substitution in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

There is the following XML:

```
<dict >
  <key>key1</key>
  <string>bla-bla</string>

  <key>key2</key>
  <int>123</int>

  <key>key3</key>
  <string>blah-blah</string>

   <!-- key... -->
   <!-- string or int tag -->
   <!-- the pair repeats several times -->
</dict>
```

I am trying to create an XSD for this file structure, and currently I am with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Test"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:complexType name ="objectType">
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name ="stringType" >
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base ="objectType">
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name ="intType">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base ="objectType">
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name ="dictType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded">
      <xs:element type ="xs:string" name ="key"/>
      <xs:element ref ="object" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name ="object" type ="objectType" abstract ="true"/>
  <xs:element name ="string" type ="stringType" substitutionGroup="object" />
  <xs:element name ="int" type ="intType" substitutionGroup="object"/>

  <xs:element name ="dict" type ="dictType" />

</xs:schema>
```

this schema lets me generate the following xmls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dict xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd">
  <key>key1</key>
  <string />
  <key>key2</key>
  <string />
  <key>key3</key>
  <int />
</dict>
```

on this stage I cannt find a way to supply some data with `<int>` and `<string>` tags.
when I am writing something like `<int>1</int>`. I see the error message. *"The element cannot contain text. Content model is empty"*

Could you please tell me if it possible full fill `<int>` tags content by integers and `<string>` tag content by strings? how?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you design an XSD for an existing or a new XML. Because of if you design a new one I would consider defining an entry node as well. I believe that would make easier to define your structure and also generated classed would be better.

```
<dict>
  <entry>
    <key>key1</key>
    <string>bla-bla</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>key2</key>
    <int>123</int>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>key3</key>
    <string>blah-blah</string>
  </entry>
</dict>
```

**EDIT:** my suggested XSD would be:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://yaugen.com/schemas" xmlns:yaugen="http://yaugen.com/schemas" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="dict">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" type="yaugen:Entry">
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:complexType name="Entry">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="key"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="string" />
                <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="int" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!!
I grade your advice about entry tag very valuable, but due to some subsiquences have to deal with the structure presented above.
so at the moment i see the the following structure suitable:
  <xs:complexType name ="dictType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded">
      <xs:element type ="xs:string" name ="key"/>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name ="int" type ="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name ="string" type ="xs:string" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to define the string and int elements as having a complex type, I can't see the reason for this. The obvious thing is to define

```
<xs:element name="string" type="xs:string" substitutionGroup="object"/>
<xs:element name="int" type="xs:int" substitutionGroup="object"/>
```

However, for this to work, object must be defined with type xs:anyType.